# What is the purpose of tips in the NFTs pallet?

Tags: pallet, nft

In pallet NFTs, I see a concept of tips:

```rust
/// The max number of tips a user could send.
#[pallet::constant]
type MaxTips: Get<u32>;
```

```rust
/// Allows to pay the tips.
///
/// Origin must be Signed.
///
/// - `tips`: Tips array.
///
/// Emits `TipSent` on every tip transfer.
#[pallet::call_index(33)]
#[pallet::weight(T::WeightInfo::pay_tips(tips.len() as u32))]
pub fn pay_tips(
    origin: OriginFor<T>,
    tips: BoundedVec<ItemTipOf<T, I>, T::MaxTips>,
) -> DispatchResult {
    let origin = ensure_signed(origin)?;
    Self::do_pay_tips(origin, tips)
}
```

What is the purpose of tips? When would a user want to tip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs of the pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/nfts):

> pay_tips: Pay tips, could be used for paying the creator royalties.

And if you see the code of the [do_pay_tips](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/nfts/src/features/buy_sell.rs#L25) is basically paying a tip to an Account related to an Item (NFT).

```
let ItemTip { collection, item, receiver, amount } = tip;
T::Currency::transfer(&sender, &receiver, amount, KeepAlive)?;
```

So basically it looks like a system that allows a way to voluntarily pay royalties to a creator.